# Install torrent CLI on montaVista 6

Tags: linux, command-line, bittorrent

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but I have never made any progress with it.

How can I install a torrent client on my NAS (Seagate Central) box which runs MontaVista 6. I have SSH and superuser access but I cannot figure out how to install any software on it.

I would like to install Transmission CLI or other torrent client like it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

------- Edit

I have tried search Google and other search engines in hope of finding something that will point me in the right direction. However I have not been able to find anything so far.

I also tried compiling a binary on ubuntu and copying it over to the NAS but this didn't work!

Comment: [This link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/2n8nfr/help_trying_to_installing_gcc_on_arm_linux/) says that running Debian on ARM architecture works well for them. But another poster says that any foreign executable gets shot down almost instantly, preventing it from being run.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if thats why I've been having issues with it! I did notice that when I set cronjobs they would get wiped off if the device restarted. I suppose I could try wipe the thing and put my own OS on it. That would allow me to do what I like.

Comment: if this device behaves like a QNAP (also ARM Linux-based) then the entire root filesystem is unpacked at boot time. The list of `cron` jobs is held in the configuration settings directly on the flash, rather than in the filesystem under `/etc/cron.d/` or `/etc/crontab`.